# giving different data() based on the element in one call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
$('a').data('goto', this.href)
```

I realize I can do this in an `each()` call but is there a way to do this in one shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`each` is the most succinct way to do this. Unlike some functions (such as `attr`), `data` doesn't support the "pass a function and have it called for every element" convention.

Why do you need a duplicate of the `href`, though?

Comment: He might be changing it and need to revert at some point, I've seen that asked for before a few times.

Comment: Love this kind of *reading between the lines*. Do you get this just from the documentation? i.e. you get clues from `.attr()` having `.attr( attributeName, function(index, attr) )` in the docs, but `.data()` missing it? If that is so, absorbing what is in the documentation takes more than casual reading.

Comment: @Majid: I'm... not sure what you meant by that exactly. Did you mean to ask something?

Comment: @Matti, This could do: Do you know a source thoroughly explaining fine differences between jquery methods - like `you cannot use this method without a septate iterator, because it has no callback function`?

Comment: @Majid: That would be [the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/). For example, on the `attr` page, if you scroll further down it even has examples for the version that has the function parameter. The `data` page doesn't have that. But the signatures at the top are a big help too.

Comment: @Majid - It makes sense to not call a function passed in to a call to `data()` because it is a way of storing any kind of data.  You may want to store a function.  How could the method determine whether the function is to be called for each element, or that the function itself is the data?

Comment: Thank you both. Good advice and good food for thought. I have a long way to go, but learning feels good, so I don't mind the distance ;)

Answer (score 0):

[`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) doesn't have a callback method like `.attr()` for instance, so probably not.  Using the `.each()` is probably the quickest way.